# Responsive filemanager upload memory limit, but only on images

Tags: memory, joomla, out-of-memory, image-uploading, responsive-filemanager

I have triyed to use Responsive filemanager with joomla but have problems with memory error when uploading images. Webhosting server is Centos 7 with php 7.0.3. When I upload larger files (such as PDF) it is ok. Only on images larger then about 1,5MB I get error low memory .... `upload.php#241`.

I think configuration in php.ini is ok:

```
upload_max_file_size=16MB
post_max_size=16MB
```

Also in config.php file in Responsive Filemanager I have:

```
'MaxSizeUpload' => 16,
```

Only the problem is with images. Can you help me find the way where look for problems in configuration ? Can it be something for example with image libraries or  something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too, it happens when I upload hires images `(approx. >8Mpix)`. I must the image oversampling, compression ratio